# What are these circles on an emulator launched from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

The green circles shown below are showing up on any device emulator I launch. Are these trying to emulate user pinching?  How do I turn them off?

[image]

*Update* In response to @SarahKhan 's answer: There is no `F1` functionality: this is all I have to work with.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This graphic is the multi-touch functionality of the emulator. You can use this functionality for actions such as pinching or any other functionality for which you'd require multiple inputs.

To remove it, make sure you are on emulator (click once on emulator to make sure).

Press F1 (or 3 menu dots at the side of emulator from where you can rotate emulators) -> Settings ->
Send Keyboard shortcuts to ->
Virtual Device (Currently it will be set as 'Emulator Controls').

Hope[image] that solves the issue.

Comment: Multi touch functionality can also be used for taking screenshots

Comment: There is no F1 or "3 menu dots"  on the App: please see the new screenshot in my question.

Comment: I have edited and added a screenshot that displays the 3 menu dots. As for F1, when you are on emulator, please click on F1 key on your laptop's keyboard